# How do I run Ubuntu 11.10 from a pendrive with an Acer BIOS?

Tags: 11.10, live-usb, acer, bios

My BIOS just "freezes" if a try to Boot from a pendrive and I have to remove the battery to restart... :( does it have a solution? I'm trying to make a clean 11.10 installation, I already have Windows 7 and Ubuntu 11.04 running in the same HDD on different partitions, not via wubi.

I think the BIOS name is "Phoenix".

My notebook is an ACER Aspire 5520-5688.

I was thinking about making a clean installation directly in the 11.04 partition, but I don't know if it is possible.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Acer makes laptops not BIOS. They buy BIOS software from AMI or Award/Phoenix.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, but this problem is pen (USB flash drive) dependent.
You can change dive and hope to boot with no problem :)

Another point is how to make it bootable, Ubuntu startup disk creator is a good tool.
If you don't have Ubuntu, you can try [LinuxLive USB Creator](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can even try unetbootin which i use i have acer lappy too. Install it from this PPA

https://launchpad.net/~gezakovacs/+archive/ppa

Once you boot your laptop put boot from USB option as first boot device.